# Null Safety is not reading the new values

Tags: flutter, dart

I get this error every time I try to run my code:

```
""New.dart:5:5: Error: The value 'null' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'int' because 'int' is not nullable.
  Y:null,""
```

Here's my code

```
void main()
{
  print (addition(
  X:1,
  Y:2,
  Z:3,));
}

int addition({int X, int Y, int Z}) {
  return X * Y * Z;
}
```

As you can see I've already given them a value and they're not null, so what's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the keyword required in front of all the `int`. You are putting them as non nullable optional parameters but without specifying default values.

```
int addition({required int X,required int Y,required int Z}) {
  return X * Y * Z;
}
```

Comment: Or you can put questions marks after the variable to make them nullable

Comment: Thanks that worked, can you explain to me why it worked with required?

Comment: Because you put them in between curly brackets, the parameters are optional.

Comment: If they are optional and not nullable, you need to give them a default value. Otherwise you need to make them not optional and put the keyword `required`

Comment: Or put them nullable (`int?`)

Comment: Don t forget to mark the answer with the ✅️

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to be passing the value anyways, you can always make the parameter required.

```dart
void main()
{
  print (addition(X:1,Y:2,Z:3));
}

int addition({required int X, required int Y, required int Z}) {
  return X + Y + Z;
}
```

If you still want to make the parameters optional:

```
void main()
{
  print (addition(X:1,Y:2,Z:3));
}

int addition({ int? X,  int? Y,  int? Z}) {

if (X!=null && Y!=null && Z!=null){
    return X+Y+Z;
} else{
    //DO this or handle it your own way.
    throw Exception('One or more parameter is null.');
  }
}
```

The reason your code is not working is that you are specifying the type as `int` but dart doesn't know whether the value will be null or not. Either you can put `required` in front to make it required which means you will have to pass the integer value on the function or you can use the `int?` which means you are expecting the value that is being passed in the function to be null. This way, you cannot return the result unless you handle the null condition.